# Assigning address of a function with different return type to a function pointer

Tags: function, pointers

int (*ptFunction) (float,char,char);

char func(float,char,char);

If we use different return types as we did in above two function declaration, will the following assignment work correctly or will give compilation error??

ptFunction = &func;

Comment: It's better for you to point out which language do you imply (C or C++)? After that it's possible to check it with a test. (I'm not a standard fan, so I could not answer this question the other way)

Comment: The above code snippet is from C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code raise an error (in g++):

```
int (*pFun)(float, char, char);

char fun1(float, char, char) {}

int main() {

  pFun = &fun1; // error: invalid conversion from char (*)(float, char, char) to int (*)(float, char, char)

  return 0;
}
```